# yasnippet won't replace default values (placeholders) in org-table caption

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet, org-table

I'm using yasnippet to create a template for org-mode tables. This works fine, and allows me to create default values (placeholders) for the column headers. The default values are highlighted by default and get replaced when I enter actual names for the columns.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: orgtable 
# key: orgtable
# --
| ${1:column A}      | ${2:column B}      | 
|--------------------+--------------------|
| $0                 |                    |
|--------------------+--------------------|
```

However, when I try to do the same thing for the org-mode caption line, it doesn't work. The default values do NOT get overwritten.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: orgtable 
# key: orgtable
# --
#+CAPTION: ${1:Title} 
| ${2:column A}      | ${3:column B}      | 
|--------------------+--------------------|
| $0                 |                    |
|--------------------+--------------------|
```

How do I get the second version of the snippet to respect the default values, i.e. overwrite them when I type?

Comment: Please try this in a minimal setup to see if one of your settings is getting in the way. The second snippet works for me (GNU Emacs 24.5.1, yasnippet version 0.8.0beta).

Comment: This is [Yasnippet bug #644](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/644)

Comment: @Constantine I can confirm that this did work correctly when I launched Emacs with `--no-init`. I'm not sure how to go about tracking down the incompatibility. My config files are extensive, so bisecting / sequentially disabling them would be impractical.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I suspect that you are using a somewhat-recent development version of yasnippet. Upgrading to [`0.9.1-snapshot`](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/releases/tag/0.9.1-snapshot) or downgrading to `0.8.0` may help.

Comment: @Constantine I think you were right. Instead of loading yasnippet from elpa manually, I tried just adding Spacemacs' auto-completion layer, which includes yasnippet. Something about that configuration fixed the problem.

Comment: That's good to hear! Do you mind writing that in an answer and accepting it so that it's clear that this issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Constantine's comment above, this seems to have been a problem with the version of yasnippet I was using. I use Spacemacs, and I resolved the problem by removing yasnippet from my manual package configuration, and instead enabling the [spacemacs auto-completion layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/auto-completion).